# Heilbronn problem on Unit Sphere

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, optimization, triangles, extremal-combinatorics

In the [Heilbronn triangle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heilbronn_triangle_problem), $n$ points are arranged with restrictions so that the smallest triangle made by a 3 point subset is as large as possible.

Consider the problem on a unit sphere using spherical triangles.  For six points, a triangular prism with triangle edge $\sqrt{2}$ and height $1/\sqrt{3}$ seems optimal, giving 14 spherical triangles of area $\pi/2$ and 6 spherical triangles of area $3\pi/2$, shown below as polygons. All vertices are distance 1 from the center.

[image: The larger triangles]

That looks like a very nice result. Using the Euler-Gauss-Simpsons Theory, somebody else found it first.  Extending the problem to more points seems non-trivial, so I'm wondering if the problem has already been studied under another name before I spend much time on it.  Are optimal results known for 7+ points?

Comment: A similar problem is to find the optimal configuration of points on sphere in order to maximise the  (Euclidean or Spherical) distance between them. Back in the mists of time I was told this problem has been solved up to $12$ points, but the solution is not known for $13$. . . I am surprised that the optimal configuration in your/Heilbronn's problem for $n=6$ is a triangular prism, I would have guessed a triangular antiprism (i.e. an octahedron !) . . . I don't really know what is already known but it is a cool problem & well worthy of consideration.